# Проблема с роутингом express+socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

Всем привет. 
Вот такая задача стоит.

Есть сервер на экспресс где инициируется сокет.
server.js:

```
...
var app = express();
var initSocket = require('./models/chats');
var groupchat = require('./models/chats/routerMiddle');
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = initSocket(server);
groupchat = groupchat(io);
app.use('/user-groupchat', groupchat);
...
```

routerMiddle.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var controllerIO = require('./io');


module.exports = function (io) {
    router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

        controllerIO(req.user, io);


        res.render('user');
    });

    return router;
}
```

initsocket.js

```
module.exports = function (server) {

    var io = require('socket.io')(server);


    return io;
};
```

и в роутере есть подключение файла io:

```
module.exports = function (user, io) {

    io.on('connect', (socket) => {
         console.log('connect');
    });

}
```

Идея заключается в том, что при авторизации в req.user лежат данные авторизованного юзера, и их частично нужно передать в реализацию сокета.

например,

```
socket.emit('update', req.user.username);
```

Описанный кусок кода - работает. Только при первом заходе на роутер, в консоль кидается имя юзера один раз. Если обновить страницу - в косоль летит два раза имя юзера. А потом три. В общем, при исполнении в роутере функции controllerIO(req.user, io); они множатся.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как оптимизировать всю эту историю? Может кто сталкивался? Или хотябы избежать дублирование ивентов в сокете при обновлении страницы.

Comment: socket.emit вы где творите при каком ивенте,и почему этот ивент вызывается несколько раз если к нему обратились один раз ? Скорее всего ошибка не в этом участке кода

Comment: socket.emit (ивент) кидаю в файле io.js который подключен в роутере. Дело в том что при отработке роутере, функция которая ловит req.user - controllerIO () отрабатывается каждый раз и сохраняет себя в сокете. И для одного соединения (при обновлении страницы) этих экземпляров может быть равно количеству обновлений.

Comment: Делают эмит в тeх eventax где конкретно им нужно.Например У вас есть event update (io.on('update' ...) который срабатывает при регистрации.Теперь надо всех слушателей этого ивента оповестить о новом пользователе
 io.on('update', (socket,req) => {
         socket.emit('update', req.user.username);
    });
А для evnt connect отдавать либо последнего зарегестриющего пользователя , либо несколько

Comment: Нука попробуйте так 
module.exports = function (user, io) {

    io.on('connect', (socket,req) => {
         console.log('connect');
         socket.emit('update', req.user.username);
    });

}

Comment: Это сработает, только к примеру- обновив страницу а событие socket.emit('update', req.user.username); сработает два раза. Ещё обновляю - три раза и тд..

Comment: Ниче не понял ,так сработает или нет ?

Comment: Сработает, только io.on("connect") задваивается.

Comment: коннется за пределами роутера а в самом роутере всего лишь emit.Хотя странно что удваивает

Answer (score 1):

нашел вот такое решение: 
Создается отдельный модуль для сокета -

```
function SocketIO(io) {
    this.io = io;
    this.socket = null;
}

SocketIO.prototype.connect = function () {
    var that = this;
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        that.io.on('connect', (socket) => {
            that.socket = socket;
            resolve(that.socket);
        });
    });

};

SocketIO.prototype.emit = function (event, data) {
    this.socket.emit(event, data);
};


SocketIO.prototype.on = function (event, callback) {
    console.log(event, callback);

   this.socket.on(event, callback);
};



module.exports = SocketIO;
```

Далее, он инициируется и вызывается в роуете -

```
module.exports = function (io) {

    router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
        let chat = new SocketIO(io);

        chat.connect().then((data)=>{
            controllerIO(req.user, data, chat.io);
        });

        res.render('user', {
            user: req.user
        });
   });

    return router;
}
```

Пока все живо и работает, мб ктото пытался так сделать, рад буду услышать советы по оптимизации.

Answer (score -1):

Если делать все хорошо, то надо прикрутить сессии, хранить их бд, с помощью какого-нибудь модуля синхронизировать сессию пользователя с подключенными сокетами. Так как сокет-соединение существует только до перезагрузки/закрытия страницы, а пользователь может открыть и несколько страниц одновременно. Только так можно организовать и личные сообщения с полноценной авторизацией, только так можно на серваке понять, какой пользователь сейчас отправляет кому сообщения. Но это чисто на будущее. Если захотите полноценный чат/мессенджер в реал-тайме с авторизацией, то советую глянуть в сторону модулей:
mongoose - модель пользователя и работа с бд.
passport - для авторизации пользователей.
express-session - хранение сессий 
express-socket.io-session - лучшая как по мне утилита для авторизации пользователя с интеграцией сокета.

Comment: Так же ваш  socket.emit('update', req.user.username);
передаёт событие всем подключенным пользователям. Если мы хотим передавать события только конкретным пользователям, нам надо знать id их сокетов или комнату. Id сокетов юзера при моем решении будет хранится в req.user, а в списке сокетов в каждом отдельном объекте действующего сокета хранится id юзера, если он зарегистрирован, а значит мы всегда можем найти, кому надо отправить сообщение.